# What is the origin of the suffix -он?

Tags: этимология, сленг, суффиксы

I learned that the Russian language has a number of words with the suffix **-он**: **музон**, **закидон**, **выпивон**, **закусон**, **расслабон**, etc. This suffix is indeed not a part of the root, as can be seen from words **музыка**, **закидывать**, **выпивать**, **закусывать**, **расслабляться**. Another example of usage of that suffix is **Черкизон**, the unofficial name of Moscow market **Черкизово**.

The common pattern seems to be that the words with that suffix are modern slang, and I got curious as to where that suffix stems from.

I asked one Russian on the Internet about that, and his response was very succinct: "Албанский учи." ("Learn Albanian.")

I thought it was a joke, but decided to check that lead and instantly found nice Albanian pop song *Hipnotizon*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1i1xcb7S0U

Did the suffix **-он** indeed come from Albanian? If so, how did it happen? I am so much surprised because Albania is a tiny state located pretty far from Russia. Or where did this suffix come from?

Comment: He/she might have meant [Олбанский язык](http://absurdopedia.net/wiki/Олбанский_язык) (*and I believe this has been discussed/mentioned under one of your numerous questions in the past*).

Comment: @Elena Latin had no -on suffix. Stadion is a Greek word (Latin is Stadium), in polygon -gon is a root ("angle" in Greek), центурион in Latin was centurio.

Comment: I think Черкизон is connected with the word "zona" (zone).

Comment: About "Албанский"... I remembered one old poem of one funny character - with elements of such slang ... or smthn like this
"Мой стих подобен алому растенью
Прибитому гвозздями к потолку
Я сочинять могу стихотворенье
При этом есть 3 пачки чипсов, тоже я могу
Вы спросите миня аткуда эти мысли?
И почему настолька я магуч?
Да потому что я сын бога
И пива нада мне не многа
Чтобы творить такии чудеса
При этом иногда в закуску пригодиться колбаса!!!!!!" ..

Comment: " Чтобы писать стихи не нада музы
достаточно одеть ритузы
и прыгать петь и громко танцевать
Стихи даны от бога да и только
Поэтому вы обязаны стих мой на веки прославлять"
"Я вызываю вас ИРЦАНЕ
на поединок слов и строк моих
Вы можете сидеть,рыгать кричать и возбжудаца
Но я уже закончил стих!" 
(c) http://irc.lv/qna/ja_kaktus_pilum_ili_ruletik_duEL 
   
мндааа... :>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there is not one but many "он" suffixes in Russian. These are written, pronounced, and mostly used in the same way (to form masculine nouns) but come from different sources entirely.

The group of words you mention specifically come from the late XX century, originating from slang and mostly remaining there.

Considering the relatively hectic and tumultuous nature of the period, you are unlikely ever to get a verifiable and concrete answer to the origin of these words.

However, judging from the connotation these words have, the kind of communities that would use them, and the speed at which these spread through the lexicon of these social groups throughout the country, the most likely guess is the idiosyncratic origin, based on a typical masculine suffix to form new fresh, nonconforming, teenage-friendly sounding words to replace their more conventional and traditional analogues.

Comment: >> *there is not one but many "он" suffixes in Russian* << What are some examples of words with other suffixes "он"?

Comment: JKlen "электрон, is borrowed from English" - it's not from English, of course. Why are you think so ? :> For a start, since antiquity there has been a metal alloy with such a Greek name. And international scientific (gr.-lat.) terms aren't exactly that is called  "the borrowing from a language", whoever introduced them.

Answer (score 5):

Nope this has nothing to do with Internet slang, all the words you’ve listed existed at least since eighties.

In fact, you are asking very interesting question - indeed the etymology `-он` as postfix should be investigated - I'm not aware of a any research of this kind (but this means nothing - I'm a mere amateur).

For instance, ["локон"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD) - a "regular" word not belonging to any slang is derived from German Locke - but how exactly it gained "-он",  is "он" in it related to other "-он"-nouns, like "расслабон", "гандон" etc.  - this should be investigated.

Oh, and this postfix also definitely has nothing to do with actual Albanian language - even if it was borrowed it was,  say, English or French where one can find plenty of such words.

Comment: @Heagon Agreed, an odd one out (an attempt of a joke, maybe?). I'd expect it to be just a corruption of *кондом*, a borrowed word, so no suffix -он here.

Answer (score 0):

As for the Albanian your Russian friend mentioned, it's not the language you might have thought of. You can read about олбанский here. http://absurdopedia.net/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA

I believe, I know just one normative word borrowed as a whole unit but having a possibility of decomposition according to the pattern mentioned above.

> **Блузон.**

This word was borrowed in the 20th century, and not so many people can say what exactly it is (if we just ask people in the street). Besides, a well-understood word блузка has existed in the Russian language for a longer while. So, блузон sounds as a neologism from блузка.

All the rest are slangish, made up in 1990-s.

Comment: the "блузон" is borrowed ? :)))) - i think it's such as omonyms with a very similar meanings. you means a very special term, but they on streets think about standart way of the slang :>

"So, блузон sounds as a neologism from блузка. " - yes...

Comment: _Blouson_ means jacket in French, so I guess it was borrowed from there, like many other fashion words.

Answer (score 0):

Just a French-Latin borrowing, I guess.
You could seen words such as фанфарон, барон, Трианон, котильон, бульон, шампиньон, павильон, батальон, регион, перрон, гормон, аттракцион, телефон, салон, баллон, донжон, эталон, миллион  and etc.  All these are  loanwords, and there are a large amount of them in the Russian language.
But the suffix has become productive at least for slang.

There is an older word "полон" -a captivity.
"Comes from a form with a second full-accord type *полънъ, from proto-slavic * Pȇlnъ of unknown origin, whence also Slavism плен, etc."
I don't think that this archaism has anything to do with the case.
There is also a Slavic word урон ... where it is the root.  ронять,уронить.

*"very succinct:"Албанский учи "*
Just the rude joke. [https://lurkmore.to/Язык_падонков](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

I suppose he had nothing to say...  :)